# Empty output with ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, processbuilder

I'm trying to execute the `iwlist` command using Java's `ProcessBuilder` but for some reason it would return an empty output, instead of the output I get when I run it in the command line.

This is my code so far:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder ("iwlist", "wlan0 scan");
builder.redirectError();
Process process = builder.start();

InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream ();  
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(stdout));

String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println (">> " + line);
}
```

But when I run the command in the terminal I get:

```
pi@naath ~ $ sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: ...
                    ESSID:"ASDQWE"
                    Protocol:IEEE 802.11bgn
                    Mode:Master
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
...
```

**UPDATE**

Oddly, using `Runtime` I can obtain the expected output as follows:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo iwlist wlan0 scan");  
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(  
                    new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));  
String line = null;  
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {  
    System.out.println(line);  
}
```

Comment: Try using `ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder ("iwlist", "wlan0", "scan")` instead

Comment: I'm not familiar with processbuilder but i'll take a stab at it. Is Java running under root? if not I would think you'd have to make "sudo" your first parameter with "iwlist wlan0 scan" as the second . EDIT: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html says to do what MadProgrammer said when setting your arguments.

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer, that made the trick

Comment: Each parameter you want to send to the command should be separated as a separate `String`, think of it like the `String[] args` of the `main` method.  This is what makes `ProcessBuilder` so useful